# Magento 2 Global Search not working for products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am using magento2ee 2.1.4. I just realized that global search for the products is not working. Here is the screen shot .[image]

while I am clicking on first search result i.e. bag in products, it is not returning right results.

So, to check this i have tried magento2ce 2.1.8 and checked the case and the same issue is found in CE also. Global search for the products is not working in any of the versions. Any idea why global search is not working in magento2 and how to fix this???

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not working either by clicking on "**Search**" icon or by pressing "**Enter**" button. This is known bug and reported to magento team by few users.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7698

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10275

Thanks